# Problems hiding or setting the audience on a link within the quick launch

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, quick-launch, audiences

Good Morning All,
I'm running into an issue where I would like to hide and show links on the quick launch based on a specific SharePoint group. I know how you can do it through the browser, but I'm to do it through code, either through a feature or master page. I do have publishing enabled which allows me to configure both the global and quick launch navigation. My first attempt was to set the "Audience" on link based on a specific SharePoint group (See code below)

```
SPNavigation spSiteNav = spWeb.Navigation;
SPNavigationNodeCollection spSiteQuickLaunch = spSiteNav.QuickLaunch;
SPNavigationNode spBaseHeading = spWeb.Navigation.QuickLaunch.Cast<SPNavigationNode>().Where(a => a.Title == "I need to").FirstOrDefault();
if (spBaseHeading != null){
    string webAppRelativePath = spWeb.ServerRelativeUrl;

    if (!webAppRelativePath.EndsWith("/")){ webAppRelativePath += "/";}
    string MemPageUrl = string.Format("{0}{1}", webAppRelativePath, "SitePages/CreateNewMemo.aspx");
                        SPNavigationNode MemoPageLink = spBaseHeading.Children.Cast<SPNavigationNode>().Where(a => a.Url == MemPageUrl).FirstOrDefault();
     MemoPageLink.Properties["Audience"] = string.Format(";;;;{0}", "Authors");
     MemoPageLink.Update();
}
```

No luck, the code sets the audience on the link, but non "Authors" members can still see the link on the quick launch.

Then I tried setting the IsVisible property (See code below):

```
SPNavigation spSiteNav = spWeb.Navigation;
SPNavigationNodeCollection spSiteQuickLaunch = spSiteNav.QuickLaunch;
SPNavigationNode spBaseHeading = spWeb.Navigation.QuickLaunch.Cast<SPNavigationNode>().Where(a => a.Title == "I need to").FirstOrDefault();
if (spBaseHeading != null){
    string webAppRelativePath = spWeb.ServerRelativeUrl;
    if (!webAppRelativePath.EndsWith("/")){webAppRelativePath += "/";}
    string MemPageUrl = string.Format("{0}{1}", webAppRelativePath, "SitePages/CreateNewMemo.aspx");
    SPNavigationNode MemoPageLink = spBaseHeading.Children.Cast<SPNavigationNode>().Where(a => a.Url == MemPageUrl).FirstOrDefault();
    MemoPageLink.IsVisible = false;
    MemoPageLink.Update();
```

}

No luck again. The property is set, but the link is still visible to non "Authors" members.

I'm lost, any help would be greatly appreciate.

Thank you in advance....

Comment: Please note, each link points to a site page that's located in the Site Pages document library.

Comment: Have you properly check the audience targeting that it is compiled!

Comment: Have you seen the answer I have provided, does it work for you?

Comment: Regarding IsVisible property, it is not intended for hiding navigation nodes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to manage audience targeting for Navigation using SSOM

`UpdateNavigationNodeAudience` method allows to set audience targeting for Navigation node:

```
 public static void UpdateNavigationNodeAudience(SPWeb web, SPNavigationNode node, Guid[] spAudienceIDs, string[] spGroupNames, string[] adGroupNames)
 {
        var audienceProps = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        audienceProps["SharepointAudienceID"] = spAudienceIDs == null ? string.Empty : string.Join(",", spAudienceIDs.Select(a => a.ToString()).ToArray());
        audienceProps["SharepointGroup"] = spGroupNames == null ? string.Empty : string.Join(",", spGroupNames);
        audienceProps["ActiveDirectoryGroupObjectLDAPPath"] = adGroupNames == null ? string.Empty : string.Join("\n", adGroupNames);
        var audienceValue = string.Format("{0};;{1};;{2}", audienceProps["SharepointAudienceID"], audienceProps["ActiveDirectoryGroupObjectLDAPPath"], audienceProps["SharepointGroup"]);
        node.Properties["Audience"] = audienceValue;
        node.Update();
 }
```

> Note: It has been tested in SharePoint 2010

**Example**

The below example demonstrates how to target Quick Launch menu nodes to **SharePoint Group** named `Authors`:

```
using (var site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
{
    using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
       var quickLaunch = web.Navigation.QuickLaunch;
       foreach (SPNavigationNode node in quickLaunch)
       {
           var spGroupNames = new[] {"Authors"};
           UpdateNavigationNodeAudience(web, node, null, spGroupNames, null);
       }
    }
 }
```

### About Audience value format in navigation

The value has the following format:

```
{SharepointAudienceID};;{ActiveDirectoryGroupObjectLDAPPath};;{SharepointGroup}
```

where

- `{SharepointAudienceID}` - SharePoint Audience ID. The delimiter `,` is used to
  specify multiple values
- `{ActiveDirectoryGroupObjectLDAPPath}` - AD Group Name. The delimiter `\n` is used to specify multiple values
- `{SharepointGroup}` - SP Group Name. The delimiter `,` is used to
  specify multiple values

---

### How to hide Pages/Webs from Navigation

Use the following properties to control page/web visibility:

- [PublishingWeb.IncludeInCurrentNavigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.publishingweb.includeincurrentnavigation.aspx) - controls whether this
  Web site is included by PortalSiteMapProvider objects that have
  NavigationType set to Current
- [PublishingPage.IncludeInCurrentNavigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.publishingpage.includeincurrentnavigation.aspx) - Gets or sets a value that
  indicates whether the PublishingPage object is included by
  PortalSitemapProviders that have NavigationType set to "Current"

The `HidePageFromCurrentNavigation` method hides page from current navigation:

```
    public static void HidePageFromCurrentNavigation(SPWeb web,string pageUrl)
    {
        var publishingWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web);
        var query = new SPQuery
            {
                Query = string.Format(@"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileRef'></FieldRef><Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where>",pageUrl)
            };
        var pages = publishingWeb.GetPublishingPages(query);
        if (pages.Count == 1)
        {
            pages[0].IncludeInCurrentNavigation = false;
        }
    }
```

The `HideWebFromCurrentNavigation` method hides web from current navigation:

```
    public static void HideWebFromCurrentNavigation(SPWeb parentWeb, string webUrl)
    {
        var web = parentWeb.Webs.FirstOrDefault(w => w.ServerRelativeUrl == webUrl);
        if (web != null)
        {
            var publishingWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web);
            publishingWeb.IncludeInCurrentNavigation = false;   
        }
    }
```

**Example**

The example demonstrates how to hide all pages and webs from current navigation:

```
using (var site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
{
    using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
       var quickLaunch = web.Navigation.QuickLaunch;
       foreach (SPNavigationNode node in quickLaunch)
       {
            var nodeType = (string)node.Properties["NodeType"];
            if (nodeType == "Page")  //Page node?
            {
                  HidePageFromCurrentNavigation(web, node.Url);    
            }
            else if (nodeType == "Area")  //Web node?
            {
                  HideWebFromCurrentNavigation(web, node.Url);    
            }
       }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For SharePoint 2013 you need to enable the Site Collection Feature "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" for audience target to work.

http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/148/t/230976.aspx